# An idiom meaning "a good horse is called a sorrel, a good young man is called fearless/crazy/bold"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, translation

Is there any idiom in English similar to

> Horse as boy, (brave) man as kook (are best).

in which *boy* means [sorrel](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sorrel_(horse)). The latter is obvious.

It is my translation(maybe it is wrong) to describe the idiom I'm seeking.

Another translation,

> “Do not be afraid to insist on your rightful case. You should know that a good horse is called sorrel, and a good young man is called crazy (brave, fearless, and bold).” ([source](https://en.osmannuritopbas.com/some-advice-from-edebali.html))

Description,

> Sorrel horses are more imposing, more muscular and stronger than other
>   horses. More powerful and warrior riders ride on horses. More powerful
>   and warrior riders ride on horses. The horse is the best, the brave is
>   alive and kicking(that is, powerful and attractive). They call them
>   unflinching, a bit stern(badass), strong, and fair, brave. Since the
>   power is money in the current period, we can compare the horse to the
>   car and the power of the valiant to money.

The idiom advised to [Osman Gazi](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Osman_I) by his father [Sheikh Edebali](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sheikh_Edebali) is originally from Turkish culture.

---

### @Edit,

The horse mentioned here is powerful, strong. And the horse possessing the features is sensed as best horse among the horse species. In the same way, a person behaving differently(may be eccentric) while solving problem, evading issues  in a genius and tricky way and smartly is sensed as best.

in Turkish,

Atın dorusu, yiğidin delisi makbuldür.

Comment: Can you explain what the idiom actually means? Is it the best combination of horse and rider? Which language/culture is it originally from?

Comment: @Pam edited question thanks for your advice.

Comment: As far as I know, and this seems confirmed by your link, sorrel refers to coloring and makes no stipulation on musculature or strength.

Comment: "The latter is obvious" - not at all. Also, I'm sure the proverb doesn't mean 'kook' or 'crazy' (as those are very negative. What exactly is the intention of the proverb (you need to explain that).  Is it that the horse (the conveyance or means) must be strong and the rider (user of the tool, the knight or man) must be ... brave?

Comment: @Cascabel the horse mentioned here is powerful, strong. And the horse possessing the features is sensed as best horse among the horse species. In the same way, a person behaving differently(may be eccentric) while solving problem, evading issues  in a genius and tricky way and smartly is sensed as best.

Comment: @Mitch  the horse mentioned here is powerful, strong. And the horse possessing the features is sensed as best horse among the horse species. In the same way, a person behaving differently(may be eccentric) while solving problem, evading issues  in a genius and tricky way and smartly is sensed as best.

Comment: You need to give the original Turkish.

Comment: @Mitch it is done

Answer (score 2):

## Stallion

You are translating, so you may need to be inventive. Idioms rarely translate directly and invention is an okay thing.

Your idiom is originally Turkish. In English culture, we respect the stallion as a kind of wild, handsome, hard to tame horse that pretty much fits your description of the man. "Stallion" [even applies directly to people in the same good way you mean](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stallion).

The full meaning is all wrapped up in that one word, if used as a metaphore and not a simile. If you need a two-part proverb, consider creating one. Here are two I thought of just for you...

> An able-minded boy starts as a bronco, but grows to become a stallion.
>
> A strong horse is a Belgian, a strong man is a stallion.

It is worth noting that in English culture, the Belgian is more commonly known than the sorrel, but you could use "sorrel" instead of "Belgian" if you must.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker, I've heard of a "sorrel" and knew it was a horse, but not what sort of house. I've never heard of a "Belgian" as a horse. But +1 for the stallion part.

Comment: Thanks for that Br-USA English difference. We see Belgian horses, then recognize and revere them, maybe that's because the Amish settlements in America provided a familiarity.